# dispatch_async vs. dispatch_sync using Serial Queues in Grand Central Dispatch

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, grand-central-dispatch

OK, I love Grand Central Dispatch and after using it with relative success but this is something I don't fully understand.

Suppose I have created my own serial queue using

```
dispatch_queue_t myQueue;
myQueue = dispatch_queue_create("myQueue", NULL);
```

After that I do this:

```
dispatch_async(myQueue, ^{
  [self doStuff1];
});

// and a few lines later...

dispatch_sync(myQueue, ^{
  [self doStuff2];
});
```

The first dispatch is async. So, it will be done concurrently, right? How can that be if myQueue is serial? How can a serial queue do things in parallel or, if you will, out of order?

thanks

Comment: In short; doStuff2 will *always* be executed after doStuff1 in the above example.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

`dispatch_async()` means that the block is enqueued and `dispatch_async()`returns to enqueueing another task/block (possibly) prior to the block being executed.

With `dispatch_sync()`, the block is enqueued and the function *will not continue enqueueing another task/block* until the block is executed.

The blocks are still executed serially.  You could execute 100 `dispatch_async()` calls, each with a block that sleeps for 100 seconds, and it'd be really fast.   Follow that with a call to `dispatch_sync()` on the same serial queue and `dispatch_sync()` will return ~10,000 seconds later.

---

To put it more simply:

```
dispatch_async(serialQ, block1);
dispatch_async(serialQ, block2);
dispatch_sync(serialQ, block3);
```

`block1` will be executed before `block2` which will be executed before `block3`.  That is the order guaranteed by the serial queue.

However, the calls to `dispatch_async()` may return *before* any of the blocks start executing.   The `dispatch_sync()` will *not* return before all three blocks are executed!

Comment: hi, but this doesn't answer the question, because what is inside the first dispatch may be executed out of order. So, if this is a serial queue how can a task execute out of the order it was submitted to the queue? I mean, we may have stuff2 being executed before stuff1... that seems illogic. Unless what you are saying is this: if I dispatch both async it will always execute in the right order. Stuff1 then Stuff2. Is this correct?

Comment: ahhhhhhhhhhhhhhh, now it is clear. Concurrency is not involved, it is a question of not waiting for completion. I thought both were involved: concurrency and waiting/not waiting. Thanks.

Comment: Right -- a common point of confusion.  GCD does a lot with very little API footprint!

Comment: @RubberDuck concurrency *is* involved - concurrency between the thread on which you call `dispatch_async` and the thread on which the block is executed. So those blocks run concurrently to the dispatching code but not concurrently to each other.

Comment: Say I want to dispatch `func1()` and `func2()` asynchronously from the main thread, but it is important that `func2()` __not start__ before `func1()` is completed.  So is it necessary to daisy-chain `func2()` after `func1()` like `^{ /*stuff for func1()*/ ; dispatch_async( /* dispatches func2 stuff */ ) ; }`, or is there another way to do this sort of thing with GCD?

Comment: Hold the phone, this makes no sense.  Why would you `dispatch_sync()` if that's going to block the calling thread _until that block completes_ instead of just calling that function directly, without using GCD?  In other words how is `dispatch_sync(myQueue, ^{
  [self doStuff2];
});` any different from just `[self doStuff2];`?

Comment: @bobobobo Queues are a cheap serialization primitive.  A serial queue guarantees execution order and serialization of execution.  Thus, dispatch `func1`, then `func2` on a serial queue... order preserved.  For the second question, that dispatch of `doStuff2` would be done to serialize `doStuff2` for whatever reason... very different from calling directly.

Comment: This is getting confused. 1. dispatch_async () just puts a block into some queue and returns immediately. It is up to the queue to process the block. 2. A serial queue executes all the blocks dispatched to it one after the other in the order they were dispatched to the queue. 3. The serial queue as a whole is concurrent with other queues, so blocks on any other queues can perform on different threads parallel to the serial queue.

Comment: From your first line: "returns potentially prior to the block being executed." you mean prior to the NEXT block right? I mean how can you return something without executing your block of code?? OR you mean CONTINUES executing the chain of blocks? I think the usage of the word 'return' here makes it kind of cryptic...

Comment: @asma22 the whole point of an asynchronous dispatch is to enqueue the block and immediately return.  If the block was enqueued on a serial queue, it may be many minutes before it is executed. Asynchronous dispatch specifically decouples enqueueing from execution.

Comment: "async": after the block/task started, in the middle, if the block is not doing work, e.g. waiting for a server response, the block can give up the thread so that the thread can do work for another block/task. Then later e.g. got server response, the previous block continue to execute where it was suspended. "Sync", the block completely occupy the thread, e.g. if the server response takes a minute, the thread simply wait and do nothing else. That's why a concurrent queue often spawn a thread for 'sync' work so the queue is not blocked.

Answer (score 4):

Neither `dispatch_async` or `dispatch_sync` change the way the block gets queued. If the queue is serial, the blocks will execute in a serial manner, if the queue is concurrent, in a concurrent manner.

The important difference between the two is that `dispatch_sync` queues the block and waits on the current execution thread until that block is executed and `dispatch_async` just queues the block and continues the execution of the subsequent instructions.

Answer (score 1):

Serial Queue can only run a single task at a time,irrespective of sync or async. Serial queues are allocated only one thread. This will be easier to understand using the below example -

Suppose there are 2 Queues A and B running tasks T1 and T2 respectively and T1 is being executed asynchronously. If control passes from A to B and B runs T2 synchronously then till the time the T2(block of code in the dispatch_sync block) completes execution T1 will be blocked. When T2 completes then T1 will resume it's execution.