# How to create a GCD queue which is always serial, even on multi-core CPUs?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, concurrency, grand-central-dispatch

As far as I understand non-main-queue GCD queues, they are serial by default only on devices with single-core CPUs. But if a device has multiple cores, it can happen that blocks in the queue get executed simultaneously.

I want to use a serial GCD queue to overcome some concurrency problems and this queue must be serial even if there are multiple cores.

A developer mentioned this is possible somehow. How would I create such a always-serial queue?

Comment: Answered at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026043/concurrency-and-serial-queues-in-grand-central-dispatch.  Use dispatch_sync on your GCD queue

Comment: @CSmith Nope. That's synchronous, not serial. If you had an async task in the queue it might run at the same time as your sync block.

Comment: @CSmith also, if the queue in question is a global concurrent queue, dispatch_sync is equivalent to dispatch_async, so that wouldn't work there either.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Standard GCD queues that can be obtained with `dispatch_get_global_queue` function are concurrent indeed.

But you can create custom gcd queue using **[dispatch_queue_create](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/dispatch_queue_create)** function. Pass `DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL` as a second parameter to create that queue as serial.

Comment: Would DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL then be serial no matter how many CPU cores there are? I worry it might be serial on a per-core basis but not entirely. How sure are you this is the trick?

Comment: @InternationalFrog, making sure that tasks are executed one after another is the main purpose of serial queues so I think you should be fine regardless of number of cores.

Comment: @InternationalFrog - Yes, serial queues that you create using `dispatch_queue_create()` are guaranteed to be serial in execution, no matter the number of cores. The blocks within them may run on different threads, but they will always execute one at a time. I use this for inexpensive locking around shared resources in a few places.

Comment: Random comment: serial is the default, so you could just use `NULL` instead of `DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL`... same same.

Answer (score 7):

To create concurrent queue: 
`dispatch_queue_t concurrentQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.aj.concurrent.queue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);`

To create serial queue: 
`dispatch_queue_t serialQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.aj.serial.queue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);`