# What is the difference between dispatch_sync and dispatch_main?

Tags: ios, multithreading, concurrency, grand-central-dispatch

I understand that `dispatch_async()` runs something on a background thread, and `dispatch_main()` runs it on the main thread, so where does `dispatch_sync()` come in?

Comment: This question indicates that you might not have seen the conceptual documentation for GCD, which would cover all these things: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/ConcurrencyandApplicationDesign/ConcurrencyandApplicationDesign.html

Comment: See also [Concurrent vs serial queues in GCD](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19179358), [Concurrency and serial queues in Grand Central Dispatch](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5026043)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't generally want to use `dispatch_main()`. It's for things other than regular applications (system daemons and such). It is, in fact, guaranteed to break your program if you call it in a regular app.

`dispatch_sync` runs a block on a queue and waits for it to finish, `dispatch_async` runs a block on a queue and doesn't wait for it to finish.

Serial queues run one block at a time, in order. Concurrent queues run multiple blocks at a time, and therefore aren't necessarily in order.

(edit)

Perhaps when you said `dispatch_main()` you were thinking of `dispatch_get_main_queue()`?

Answer (score 2):

`dispatch_main()` is not for running things on the main thread — it runs the GCD block dispatcher. In a normal app, you won't need or want to use it.

`dispatch_sync()` blocks the current thread until the block completes. This may or may not be the main thread.

If you want to run something on the main thread, you can use `dispatch_get_main_queue()` to get the main queue and use once of the normal dispatch methods to run a block there.